# Where to put generated string-resoures that will be included in R.class generation and can be used in layouts?

Tags: android, xml, android-resources, generated, gradle-task

I'm having a custom *JavaExec gradle task*

which I currently use for generating several string resource files for android and other platforms.

I found out that when I'm using gradle directly, like this:

```
buildTypes {
     debug {
         resValue "string", "test", "test-value"
     }
}
```

Gradle will generate me a

> generated.xml

under

> /build/generated/resValues/{debug}/values/

[image: generated res value directory]

depending on my active {buildType}

**For the gradle way it works, but I don't want to use gradle directly for generating my resValues. I want to use my custom script instead!**

Well, but when my script generates for example a *generated-custom.xml* it does not work as it should.
It generates the R.class file correctly, but when I want to use my generated string resources in a layout it won't find any of these.

**So my question is:**
Where do I need to put the generated xml file, so that:

- The R.class is generated with these string items
- The string items can be used in layouts aswell (@string/generated_string_key)

Thanks!

Comment: You're saying that even after a clean + Gradle sync you can't just use R.string.test  or @string/test?

Comment: I can use R.string.test but cannot use @string/test that's why I am a bit confused and thought I was missing a configuration somewhere?

Comment: Very strange. I have followed the same approach in the past and it worked fine. Try compiling anyway, maybe the IDE will "find" the resource at compile time.

Comment: I will give it a try in a minute! Did you also put the generated file under the resValues/{buildType}/values directory when you did the approach on your project?

Comment: No. It just worked. No copy paste or anything like that

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that. Let me ask you this: Did you also generate the files directly in this directory? :D

Comment: Sorry don't remember...